# How to avoid two different user submitting same request for the same person at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, transactions

How to avoid two different users submitting same request for the same person at the same time?
This is a helpdesk ASP.NET webforms app with SQL server as the backend.

I have a transaction block in my stored procedure which does the insert to the request table.

But still when my colleague and I tested this scenario in just milliseconds our requests went through even choosing the same option which we validate for duplicate in the stored procedure.

Comment: Can you share your store procedure snipped ?

Comment: You might want to research "pessimistic vs optimistic locking".

Comment: This typically arises when the code is structured to check some condition and, based on the result, proceed with another action.  If the check and action are not protected by some sort of lock that makes the operation atomic then you have created a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_Condition#Software).

Comment: What defines "same person" or even "same request" for that matter?  In other words it sounds like you have 2 users, filling out a trouble ticket page, both picking the same value for the *person* reporting the issue and both hitting submit.  If that's true, then a blocking stored procedure isn't going to be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to define the logic for comparing if 2 requests are the same.

From the information you gave us, the only variables I can see are (a) Person (b) Time.
For example, 2 requests could be considered the same, if (a) they belong to the same person id and (b) were recorded within X minutes of each other.

However the above rule is too generic and might result in loosing valid requests. So I would suggest the following:

1. Investigate why more than one user can submit the same request. What is the frequency of such cases? What are the reasons it happens? With this knowledge you might arrive at a very different and better solution.
2. Check for further variables to add to the rule e.g. request type, application.
3. If the frequency of duplicate requests is very low, consider using a generic rule and whenever you detect a duplicate, show it to the user, and ask for confirmation to add or cancel his new request.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said enough about your stored procedure to suggest how to fix it, but it seems to me that any blocking like this should be implemented in the application code.  You could use a ConcurrentDictionary to keep track of currently-running requests and either block until they complete or return an error of some kind.

That said, this sounds like a mis-feature.  Are you sure this is required?  Is there a better solution to the big-picture problem you are trying to solve?